# Web scraping Access denied | Cloudflare to restrict access

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to access and get data from [www.cclonline.com](http://www.cclonline.com) website using python script.
this is the code.

```
import requests
from requests_html import HTML

source = requests.get('https://www.cclonline.com/category/409/PC-Components/Graphics-Cards/')
html = HTML(html=source.text)
print(source.status_code)
print(html.text)
```

this is the errors i get,

```
403
Access denied | www.cclonline.com used Cloudflare to restrict access
Please enable cookies.
Error 1020
Ray ID: 64c0c2f1ccb5d781 • 2021-05-08 06:51:46 UTC
Access denied
What happened?
This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.
```

how can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a User-Agent header like what Mozilla might send, and also add a Referer (sic) header with a page URL that might refer to the URL you want to scrape, e.g. whatever URL you end up at if you browse to the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the site's [robots.txt](https://www.cclonline.com/robots.txt) does not explicitly says no bot is allowed. But you need to make your request look like it's coming from an actual browser.
Now to solve the issue at hand. The response says you need to have cookies enabled. So that can be solved by using a headless browser like [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). Selenium has everything a browser has to offer (it basically uses google chrome or a browser of your chosen as a driver). It will make the server think the request is coming from an actual browser and will return a response.

Learn more about how to use selenium for scraping [here](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/selenium-python/).

Also remember to adjust crawl time accordingly. Make pauses after each request and swap user-agents often.

Comment: Thanks, this help to solve my issue. i have another question is there are any method to pass reCAPTCHA because using selenium i couldn't pass it

Comment: I am afraid not. There are some services that offer such thing. But automating a reCAPTCHA bypass is not a common thing as of my knowledge. The encded token populated for each  reCAPTCHA is verified from both server end and backend. So even if you capture the reCAPTCHA token in front end. Without solving that won't get you the token required it to be considered "SUCCESSFUL".  I hope you understood. Sorry if my English is not good.

Answer (score -1):

There’s no a silver bullet for solving cloudflare challenges, I’ve tried in my projects the solutions proposed here on this website, using playwright with different options https://substack.thewebscraping.club/p/cloudflare-how-to-scrape