# Python requests error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am using an API that returns links and examples of Latin words in ancient texts. I would like to parse the response as JSON but I am receiving the following error:

> File "C:\Users\{name}\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in
> raw_decode
> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
> 0)

Here is my code:

```
    def get_concordance(self, word):
        data = requests.get(f"https://latin.packhum.org/rst/concordance/{word}?authmax=3&max=10000000")
        print(data.content)
        data = data.json()

        return data
```

When printing `data.content` it appears to be HTML not JSON, however, if you visit the URL with a Latin word in the `{word}` field, it displays a list of JSON objects.

Comment: So is your question "how to parse HTML as JSON", or "how to parse HTML as HTML", or "why is `data.content` not JSON"?

Comment: @mkrieger1, going to this url returns a list of JSON objects:https://latin.packhum.org/rst/concordance/insula?authmax=3&max=10000000 But `data.content` is HTML. So, why is `data.content` not JSON and why am I getting an error when trying to parse it as JSON?

Comment: Looks like you're getting 403'd by Cloudflare.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67444887/web-scraping-access-denied-cloudflare-to-restrict-access

Comment: Instead of using Selenium or Puppeteer, I just added a "User-Agent" header to the request. Header: `headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"} requests.get(url, headers=headers)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A late post but here's the answer. The API I was hitting blocks the default `user-agent` (what type of device the request is coming from) that the `requests` library uses. My solution was to manually set a `user-agent` field on the requests like so:

```py
def get_concordance(word):
        url = f"https://latin.packhum.org/rst/concordance/{word}?authmax=3&max=10"
        headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}

        requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

This makes the API think that you are requesting from a real user in the browser instead of a bot.